# How I can connect the LEGO SPIKE Prime hub via Bluetooth in Visual Studio Code using the pybricksdev library?

Tags: programming, bluetooth, spike-prime, pybricks

I'm trying to send some data from the hub to the terminal for some debug. But I can't figure out how I can connect the hub via Bluetooth to my PC. I tried to look in the [API documentation](https://docs.pybricks.com/projects/pybricksdev/en/latest/api/ble/index.html) and maybe I found something but I'm not sure.

Comment: Pybricks is great, so is the support they provide, I think you'd be better of asking your question there: https://github.com/pybricks/support/

Comment: Hi tom and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you show us what have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use `pybricksdev` is as a command line tool. I recommend using [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) to ensure that your are always using the latest version of `pybricksdev`.

Assuming you have already installed `pipx` and you have a terminal open in VS Code in the same directory as the script you want to run, run the following command:

```
pipx run pybricksdev run ble my_script.py
```

Where `my_script.py` is replaced with the actual name of the script you want to run.